# Doctrine2 sluggable on condition

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'd like to use the sluggable bahaviour but on certain condition. I configured it like so :

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title"}, updatable=false)
 * @ORM\Column(length=255, unique=true)
 */
protected $slug;
```

By default I want a slug to be generated on all persists, whereas I want the slug to be updated only if specific conditions are valid.

In my entity listener, I did

```
public function preUpdate($product_culture, PreUpdateEventArgs $event)
{

    if ($event->hasChangedField('title')) {
        $this->getProductCultureService()->setProductCulture($product_culture);

        if ($this->getProductCultureService()->isSluggable()) {
            $product_culture->setSlug(null);
        }
    }
}
```

The slug is correctly generated on persist, the condition is ok, but when I set the slug to `null` so it can be regenerated, I end up with `null` in database.

The doc says that the slug must be set to null in order to regenerate it.

Do you know what I'm missing ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe your update event should be executed before the update event of a Sluggable bundle. Have you tried to set the order when you bind the event?

Comment: go to Gedmo\Sluggable\SluggableListener and check what is happening in generateSlug() for your object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to my problem.
I don't know why but the sluggable listener has almost all its function in private mode. It is very frustrating because it is impossible to extend it. 
So I copied it and added my logic to the onFlush method.

Now it works fine.